# how to Filter two models values in query sets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

hi I'm Django rest framework in my I want to search filter 2 models at once

```
 
class SearchViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
 queryset = Profile.objects.all()
 serializer_class = SearchSerializer
 authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
 filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
 search_fields = ["user__username", "caption", "post_text"]

 def get_queryset(self):
 search_query = self.request.GET.get("search")
 queryset = super().get_queryset()

 if search_query:
 # Filter the queryset based on the search query
 queryset = queryset.filter(user__username__icontains=search_query)
 # Get the related Post objects that match the search query
 post_queryset = Post.objects.filter(
 caption__icontains=search_query) | Post.objects.filter(
 post_text__icontains=search_query)
 # Get the distinct Profile objects that have related matching Post objects
 queryset = queryset.filter(posts__in=post_queryset).distinct()

 return queryset
```

this is my serilizers. py

```
 
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
 model = Profile
 fields = "__all__"
 depth = 1


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
 model = Post
 fields = "__all__"

class SearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 profile = ProfileSerializer()
 posts = PostSerializer(many=True)
```

I want to filter results by username as well as post description and post caption
but the username belongs to ProfileSerilizers and the post description and post caption belongs to Post Sterilizers
how can I achieve this

I'm getting this error

```
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'posts' into field. Choices are: bio, id, id_user, location, profileimg, user, user_id
```

Comment: [django-filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Comment: Hi, filters work on models and model relationships, not the serializers, can you show us those relationships? Like Ross mentioned, when working with complex filters the django-filter package offers great features!